# The results is different when placing torch.distributed.rpc.rpc_aync at a different .py file

Tags: pytorch, rpc

I want to execute a function at the worker side and return the results to the master. However, I find that the results is different when placing rpc_async at a different .py file

##### Method 1

master.py:

```py
import os
import torch
import torch.distributed.rpc as rpc
from torch.distributed.rpc import RRef
from test import sub_fun

os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = '10.5.26.19'
os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '5677'

rpc.init_rpc("master", rank=0, world_size=2)
rref = torch.Tensor([0])
sub_fun(rref)
rpc.shutdown()
```

test.py

```py
def f(rref):
print("function is executed on master")

def sub_fun(rref):
x = rpc.rpc_async("worker", f, args=(rref,))
```

worker.py:

```py
import os
import torch
import torch.distributed.rpc as rpc
from torch.distributed.rpc import RRef

os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = '10.5.26.19'
os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '5677'

def f(rref):
print("function is executed on worker")
rpc.init_rpc("worker", rank=1, world_size=2)
rpc.shutdown()
```

I found that the output is "function is executed on master" at the worker side.

##### Method 2

when I put the two functions: sub_fun and f in the master.py rather than the test.py, the result is "function is executed on worker".

Why the two ways output the different results. and how can I get the result 2 with the method 1.

Answer (score 0):

RPC assumes that the modules and functions are consistent across all processes. In this case, you have the same function `f` with different implementations across two processes. Note that RPC does not ship the entire function code to the remote side for execution but only finds the function `f` on the remote side and execute whatever exists there.

I'd suggest using two different functions to achieve what you are trying to do here since depending on how you import files, one function implementation might override the other.